# Getting the VTK widget working with Qt Creator

Tags: qt, qt-creator, vtk

I want to use the VTK widget in Qt Creator. So, I downloaded and installed Qt Creator 4, and in `/usr/lib/qt4/plugins/designer` there is now the file `libQVTKWidgetPlugin.so`. However, on starting a new Qt Creator Widgets project, and entering the Design tab, there are no additional widgets listed on the left, only the default ones such as Push Button, Label, etc. What additional steps do I need to show the VTK widget so that I can just drag and drop it onto the GUI I am building?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I worked with VTK and Qt almost a year ago, I hope that the refernces I have still valid nowadays.

If so, you should go under `C:\vtk\VTK5.10.1\vs10\bin\Release` (or a similar path, depending on the version of VTK you've installed), and localize two files: `QVTKWidgetPlugin.lib` and `QVTKWidgetPlugin.dll`. If they are there, there are good chances you've built VTK properly.

Now copy those files in `C:\Qt\4.x.x\plugins\designer`.

if everything goes well, then open the QT designer. You will find the `VTK WINDOW WIDGET` at the bottom of the qt widget list like this snapshot:

[image]

**Reference:** http://guitarcplusplus.blogspot.it/2013/02/itk-vtk-qt-on-window-7-64bit-and-visual.html

Comment: Thanks, but I'm working in Linux, and the only relevant file I have after building VTK is `libQVTKWidgetPlugin.so`, and there is no `libQVTKWidgetPlugin.a` (what would be the Linux equivalent of libQVTKWidgetPlugin..dll) ...

Comment: OK, I see. Unfortunately, I've never worked with VTK on Linux; I think I cannot be on any help, there...

Answer (score 1):

Promoting a normal widget or simply changing the code behind the widget class to inherit from the VTK one is the best way to do it imho. The problem with the VTK widget plugin for Qt creator is that you have to keep it up to date with your Qt creator. Even when you update your VTK build with a newer version of Qt you still have to keep the old one around plus the sources of Qt Creator. You cannot use a plugin for Qt Creator built with a different version of Qt from the one your Creator is using. This is an overhead that is rarely worth the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of time later but... maybe you can add a QWidget and promote it to QVTKwidget. I saw it here http://hxr99.blogspot.com.co/2013/03/qt-vtk-displaying-dicom-series-using.html . It may not appear  listed as a widget, but if the libraries are correctly installed it will still compile and find everything.